# table not allow to create and edit in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Django table not allow to edit and create.

**Before editing the table**
[image]

**I changed is active true and taken user illyas**
[image]

**But after saving is active false and taken user None.... WHY???**
[image]

**models.py**

```
class SignupCupon(models.Model):
    offer_for = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Referral offer")
    cupon_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    offer_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    which_user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="which_user_signup", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    taken_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="signup_cupon_taken_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "User: " + str(self.which_user) + " - Cupon: " + str(self.cupon_code)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cupon_code == "":
            self.cupon_code = generate_cupon()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CategoryOffer, ProductOffer, CuponOffer, SignupCupon, ReferralCupon


admin.site.register([CategoryOffer, ProductOffer, CuponOffer, SignupCupon, ReferralCupon])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` only gets called if the if statement is True (if there is no `cupon_code`) so in your case it never gets called. Try calling it regardless of the if statement:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.cupon_code == "":
        self.cupon_code = generate_cupon()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's working...You saved my day. lot of thanks